# Export SQL query results as XML in DB2 script

Tags: sql, xml, command-line, db2

I'm trying to query a lot of system/database information in an SQL script to be run on DB2 Linux/Unix/Windows.
Ideally the output should be both machine readable and at least somewhat comprehensible for humans.

As formatting the output in DB2 CLP seems erratic (or I'm too newb) I tried to output stuff as XML and process it later on, something like:

```
VALUES ('<?xml version="1.0"?>');
SELECT REC2XML(1.0, 'COLATTVAL', 'row', NAME, VALUE, DEFERRED_VALUE) FROM SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG ORDER BY NAME;
```

This works ok; I get output I can probably process further.

However, when I try to run REC2XML with a function such as current_timestamp:

```
SELECT Current_timestamp FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

I can't use REC2XML as that only seems to support column selects.

Not having much DB2 knowledge:

1. Is there a better/easier way to generate XML output from an SQL script
2. Is there some way to also output the results of functions such as current_timestamp as XML?

Note that I'm after an SQL script (not a shell script); if possible I would like to keep it usable on Windows, Linux and Unix machines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't know of a better way.
2. You can get XML output of functions like this:

   ```
   Select REC2XML(1.0, 'COLATTVAL', 'row', ct) From (SELECT current timestamp as ct FROM sysibm.sysdummy1);
   ```

Comment: Thanks vikrantislav, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This function does not exist in DB2 for zOS. The alternate is to use `XMLFOREST` to generate a column set and `XMLAGG` to merge the rows.

```
SELECT
xmlserialize(
    xmlelement(
        name "employees",
        xmlagg(
            xmlelement(
                name "employee",
                xmlforest(
                    EMPNO as "empno",
                    SURNAME as "surname",
                    MIDNAME as "midname",
                    FIRSTNAME as "firstname",
                    HIREDATE as "hiredate"
                )
            )   
            order by EMPNO
        )
    AS CLOB VERSION '1.0' INCLUDING XMLDECLARATION
    )
)
from EMPLOYEES
```

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><employees><employee><empno>12345</empno> ...
```

Comment: This is also the proper way with DB2 for i ;-)

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-xmlserialize

SELECT e.empno, XMLSERIALIZE(XMLELEMENT(NAME "Emp",
                                         e.firstnme || ' ' ||e.lastname)
                             AS CLOB(100) **CCSID** 1208) AS "result"
        FROM employee e WHERE e.lastname = 'SMITH'